# NullReferenceException in WebSecurity.Login FormsAuthentications.SetAuthCookie when unit testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to unit test, with the build-in Visual Studio test tools, a controller action that uses FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(string,boolean) to set up forms authentication for a user. The problem is that when I call it I get a NullReferenceException. None of the objects in the call are null so the exception must be related to something else that the method tries to use.

I am already mocking (using Moq) the ControllerContext in order to resolve some other values. However, I don't know what (if anything) I can mock to get SetAuthCookie to work.

The SetAuthCookie(string,boolean) method is called through the WebSecurity.Login(string,string,boolean) method

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the method is static and not mockable. You can however wrap it up in a service of some sort which is interfaced and test against it.

```
public interface IAuthenticationService
{
    void SetAuthCookie(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie);
)

public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    public void SetAuthCookie(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
    }
}
```

So now you can have an `IAuthenticationService` in your controller and test that the `SetAuthCookie` method is called when it should be.